Proof of funds without payslips for UK visitor visa application
I have a question regarding the proof of funds for the UK visitor visa. I have searched for similar cases but have not found an answer to my specific question.
I am aware that proof of funds needs to include payslips and bank statements. My sister has returned to education to finish her bachelor's degree and has no income since she is not working (not working since 2021 because of political situation). However, she has savings that are not currently deposited in a bank account. Due to a bank crisis, she withdrew all her money in 2021. If she were to apply for a standard UK visitor visa, she would need to open a new bank account, deposit the money, and wait for six months to apply for the visa.
What can be done to prevent this from appearing as fund parking? Should she deposit the money in the form of a fixed deposit and provide a fixed deposit letter? Are payslips mandatory?

While likely not essential to answer this question, it can be helpful to edit in her nationality. People from some countries have more problems to get visa, it helps if we know if she is from such country or not.

@Willeke She's from Myanmar. I'm sorry I forgot to add the nationality

One solution would be to get bank statements going back to prior to the withdrawal of the cash and provide those with the application, plus evidence of her employment at that time eg relevant tax return(s). Normally bank statements or letters issued more than 1 year before the date of application are specifically not required, however in the circumstances you describe you should be able to give an explanation that might be accepted. However, if your sister has had no income since 2021, bear in mind that UKVI might question how she has supported herself since then if she has not used (any of) her cash savings. Proving that an amount of cash withdrawn in 2021 is the same amount of cash in 2024 is difficult and may stretch UKVI’s credulity.
IMHO putting the cash in an FD is not a solution to being able to apply immediately. UKVI would still want to see evidence that your sister obtained those funds legally.
See also the Provenance of funds section in UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')
